# Page headers on SSRS subreports in grouped table

Tags: reporting-services, header, ssrs-2008, subreport, ssrs-grouping

I have a multiple page report.  It takes 3 parameters: start date, end date, and job number.

They have requested the ability to run this report for all jobs or multiple jobs at a time.  I created a second report and made the job number parameter allow multiple values.  I then created a table, grouped by the job number, and added my original report as a subreport in a row.

This all works great.  Except that the page headers from the subreport do not show.  I can easily get the info to show at the start of the report by adding it to the table grouping, but I can't figure out if there's any way to get it to show on each page.

If each job's report is 4-5 pages and they run it for 25 jobs, they really need to have the corresponding job number on the top of each page.  Some people have suggested putting it as the table header and checking the option to show on each page, but that won't change per job and I don't think it works if the subreport spans multiple pages anyway.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually headers and footers in sub-report will not display in the report.

The best way is group by "job number" add a row above inside the group, put job number in that. Then go to job number group properties and select "Page Break" for each instance of group.